# Steps to publish express js application in IIS

Tags: node.js, express, iis, tedious, express-handlebars

Could anyone suggest me what are the exact steps to be followed to publish express js node application in `IIS` locally? Most of the links which i referred has web.config file. I am not clear whether it should be generated by our own. My project involves `express js 4.14.0` with `handlebars 4.0.1` and `tedious` for DB connection. Also, please tell me the prerequisites and installations required in step by step manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to check https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode for a guide.

Comment: Answers that only contain a link tend to get downvoted/ removed. Please include the explanation of the solution in your answer so that the answer is preserved should the link break.